# Android pull image to reveal full size image

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to achieve the following on a relative layout.

[image]

It's similar to WhatsApp profile image style and I think Google uses it on the YouTube app too. I've searched around but can't find anything as I don't know what it's called.

Is there a library or possibly anyone who's used/achieved a similar feature?

The purpose is to use minimum height as needed as some images are portrait and can take up full height of screen not allowing user to realise there's more under it.

I'm using a scrollview xml with a relative layout.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Lots of Google searching. No luck as I simply do not know the concept.

Comment: library : https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView . I think there should be a way to do it with coordinator now, but dont know the details.

Comment: @poss checking it now and will report back. Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard using a touch listener I wouldn't think. Just detect if the down event is within the image view's range and if so see if they swipe down during the move event and if so change the height of the image to whatever the swipe distance is up to a maximum of the images size. I mean that is just a guess I haven't really tried something like this before but I would think it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @zgc7009 Sounds feasible the way you described. Not in my capacity and experience range unfortunately. I think this might be an option from poss's suggestion but it's built on Android Studio http://ksoichiro.github.io/Android-ObservableScrollView/docs/basic/flexible-space-with-image

Comment: Not even gonna lie I am kind of interested in this now. If you haven't figured out how to port that over, someone hasn't given you an acceptable answer, or you can't figure it out by the time I do will very likely sit down and figure out a smooth/simple/clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called a Parallax Effect, not really sure, but here are some libraries that do some similar stuff using listviews:

https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView

https://github.com/Frank-Zhu/PullZoomView

Comment: ParallaxListView tested just now and it adds an image above the listview which when pulled zooms in. So it's the reverse of what I want but a very interesting idea. Going to test second one now.

Comment: The second link seems like exactly what I need. Unfortunately I'm having extreme trouble importing it with Eclipse. The instructions on that page aren't clear or don't work anymore so I can't test it. I guess I might have to switch to Android Studio soon just for this.

Comment: You should definitely switch to Android Studio. It's the official IDE now. Every modern library is nowadays distributed as an AS project. Importing your current project to AS isn't hard.